# Wordpress category display child only one level

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a theme which shows an overview of child categories with title, link and description when entering a category archive. However, I only want to show child categories one level below the current category, and not the children of child categories.

How do I do that?

```
<?php
global $ancestor;
$childcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $cat . '&hide_empty=1');
foreach ($childcats as $childcat) {
  if (cat_is_ancestor_of($ancestor, $childcat->cat_ID) == false){
    echo '<li><h2><a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">';
    echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a></h2>';
    echo '<p>'.$childcat->category_description.'</p>';
    echo '</li>';
    $ancestor = $childcat->cat_ID;
  }
}
?>
```

I found that code, but it only returns one child. It returns. (Faa and Faq are child categories)

- Faa
- Faq -- Not displayed

Thanks!

Comment: Does 'FAQ' has any posts?

Comment: Nope, it did not have that, but i did add one! Now it displays like this.

- Faa - Faq - Faa -Faq so it displays the hole list for every category that have a post under it.

Comment: Srry, the code was in the loop! Yeah Now it displays only one category not any childs =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure 'FAQ' has post under it. If you notice the "code you found" is passing the parameter "&hide_empty=1" which means it will not return categories that are empty.

So your options are to either remove that or make sure your category has posts under it.